# Create Lambda in CloudFormation with unknown ImageUri property

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

I'm building my infrastructure on AWS with CLoudFormation and I want to create a Lambda Function that pull the code image from ECR. So I added to my CloudFormation template one Lambda resource depending on a ECR repository resource.
The problem is that Lambda template requires the "imageUri" properties, but actually I don't know it because the image does not exists and the ECR repository is not created yet.

Should I first create an ECR and push the image and only then edit the whole CLoudformation template adding the Lambda resource?

Honestly I don't like this approach since I prefer my whole infrastructure would be built before any software work.

Comment: You can create the ECR in the cf than push the image to the ECR with a custom resource (CR) you can than ask for the arn of the image end return it to the CR. Then you use the !Get.att on the CR that will have the arn for you lambda.

Comment: Ok, but as I said this solution needs an image to be developed, build and pushed before the Lambda creation on CF. I want to find a solution to prevent this.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible. The best you could get is to build a 'hello world' type container and use that in the lambda. You can then update the lambda when you've written the real thing.